# displaying navbar according to user roles and permisions laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, user-roles

I am implementing user roles in laravel 5 and I want to update the navbar according to the user permissions. The default navbar has A, B, and C menus which redirect to the specific pages. Let's say that user 1 can view page A and B, while user 2 can view only C. When user 1 logs in, I want the navbar to show only A and B menus. I want to do this in a single page and don't want to create a master page for every user role (as was suggested to me). Any help or hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you need to explain how your roles are set up in your system. So consider that the following example has some assumptions...

If for example your `User` model has a relationship to a `Roles` model, as so:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Role');
}
```

You can then add a method to your User model to check if a User has a certain role:

```
public function hasRole($name)
{
    foreach ($this->roles as $role) 
    {
        if ($role->name == $name) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can then do something like this in your nav view (using blade)

```
@if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin'))
  <!-- nav links here -->           
@endif
```